# How can I set a session variable from inside a monkeypath on String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, pg-search

I'm getting the following error...

```
pry("serp")> session[self.to_sym] = "closed"
NameError: undefined local variable or method `session' for "serp":String
```

...when I try to set a session variable from within a monkeypatch on the String class. (Necessary so I can track the progress of a job in delayed job in order to load my search results only when they are ready.)

How can I set a session variable there? Or is there a better solution?

My code...

**/config/initializers/string.rb**:

```
class String
  def multisearch
    result = PgSearch.multisearch(self)
    session[self.to_sym] = "closed"
    return result
  end
end
```

**/app/views/searches/show.html.haml**:

```
- if @term.present? && session[@term.to_sym] == "open"
  %h1 Search In Progress
  # then show spinning wheel animation etc
- else
  %h1 Search Results
  = form_tag search_path, :method => :get do
    = text_field_tag "term", "Search term"
    = submit_tag "Search"
  - unless @results.blank?
    # then show the search results etc
```

**/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    - if @term.present? && session[@term.to_sym] == "open"
      %meta{:content => "5", "http-equiv" => "refresh"}/
```

**/app/controllers/searches_controller.rb**:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  filter_access_to :all  
  def show
    if @term = params[:term]
      session[@term.to_sym] = "open"
      @results = @term.delay.multisearch
      # other stuff...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to stop fighting Ruby's OO nature and to build a Search model that could own everything I needed to access.

**/app/models/search.rb**:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :results
  def multisearch
    results = PgSearch.multisearch(self.term).to_a
    self.update_attributes :results => results, :status => "closed"
    return results
  end  
end
```

** /app/controllers/searches_controller.rb**:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController  
  respond_to :html
  def show
    if params[:term].present?
      @search = Search.find_or_create_by_term(params[:term])
      if @search.status.blank?
        @search.delay.multisearch
        @search.status = "open"
        @search.save
      elsif @search.status == "closed"
        @search.update_attributes :status => nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**/app/views/searches/show.html.haml**:

```
- if @search.present? && @search.status == "open"
  # progress bar etc
- else
  = form_tag search_path, :method => :get do
    = text_field_tag "term", "Search term"
    = submit_tag "Search"
- if @search.present? && @search.status.nil?
  - unless @search.results.blank?
    # show the search results
```

**/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml**:

```
- if @search.present? && @search.status == "open"
  %meta{:content => "5", "http-equiv" => "refresh"}/
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the session as a parameter.

```
class String
  def multisearch session
    result = PgSearch.multisearch(self)
    session[self.to_sym] = "closed"
    return result
  end
end
```

Then

```
@term.delay.multisearch(session)
```

Comment: Thanks! That didn't work I'm afraid. I've decided to stop fighting the OO and have started building a Search model to own all this stuff. When I get it working I'll return to post an answer. But first I've got to fix a painful serialization issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671773/why-cant-i-save-an-object-with-a-serialized-attribute