# Why can't I save an object with a serialized attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, pg-search

I have...

**/app/models/search.rb**:

```
serialize :result  
def multisearch
  self.result = PgSearch.multisearch(self.term)
  self.status = "closed"
  self.save
  return result
end
```

**/db/schema.rb**:

```
create_table "searches", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "term"
  t.string   "status"
  t.text     "result"
end
```

I get the following error when I try `self.save?

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
from /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/expressions.rb:3:in `count'
```

I get a similar error when I test `result.serialize`:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
from /Users/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:49:in `serialize'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to convert to an array before serialization: `self.result = PgSearch.multisearch(self.term).to_a`